# Apache Nutch 1.17, Dump parsed content with some metadata into JSON

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I have setup Nutch 1.17 to crawl some data. After downloading, I have to import that data to JSON. It should contain parsed text, title, timestamp, URL. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, [indexer-csv](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/IndexWriters#IndexWriters-CSVindexerproperties) could be used as first step (conversion of CSV to JSON would be the second step). Indexer-csv allows to configure which [Nutch index fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/IndexStructure) to export - title, URL ("id"), timestamp ("tstamp") and parsed text ("content") are provided as standards fields or via the plugin "index-basic".

Comment: Yes it looks better to server my purpose.

Comment: Sir, this indexer cannot be used in cloud mode according to my search. Isn't it ?\

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, this is still the case. There is an issue open (NUTCH-2793) to enable indexer-csv in distributed mode but there's no solution available right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [PR #490](https://github.com/apache/nutch/pull/490/) which closed issue [NUTCH-1863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1863). This allows you to dump the CrawlDB into a JSON format (check the `-format` flag).

One potential drawback is that this tool probably will not output the exact format that you want/need (different field names), but it should be a good starting point (and it should contain more data than what you need).

Ultimately you could implement a custom class to dump the content of a segment in your desired format. You could use [SegmentDump.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/nutch/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/segment/) class as a base implementation.